# How to validate password and redirect admin to admin page and user to user page using roles?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

This is my code:

```
protected void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["userDatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select role from accounts", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string role = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["role"]);


            if (role == "a")
            {
                Response.Redirect("AdminPage/adminAccount.aspx");
             }
            if (role == "u")
            {
                Response.Redirect("UserPage/userAccount.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {

            //record is not in ur table
        }

    }
}
```

Role `a` is for admin, and role `u` is for users.

How do I validate and redirect the users who are logging in correctly?

Right now this code will redirect me to the admin home page whenever I click login, whether or not the username and password are correct.

What do I need to add in to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no idea what your are doing

Please make some logic as i am trying to explain your

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select role from accounts", conn);
```

This line will return all the users right?

But you need specific users data so write like this

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select role from accounts where username='"+yourusernametextbox.text+"' and password='"+yourpassword.text+"'--", conn);
```

This will return the true result where role is admin or user

And now One suggestion for you

Formatting queries like this may result into sql injection rather please use parametrized queries

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I am very very lost in this, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select role from accounts where Username=@Username and Password=@Password", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: Much better answer than other 2 with using parameters!! +1

Answer (score 0):

Where are your password and username strings? How are you checking if the ones user have entered are valid? When you get them, you can use them in the following way:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select role from accounts where username = '" + usernameString + "' and password = '" + passwordString + "'", conn);
```